# CKeditor content styled as the frontend design

Tags: css, ckeditor

I am currently making a design where a CKeditor is managing the content in a 960px wide container. Well the content inside that box is in two columns, which is just two divs, that is styled with div:first-child and div:nth-child(2) .. What I want is to make the CKeditor have these to div's pr. default and have them styled as in my frontend design - is that possible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either edit `/contents.css` to reflect the final look within the editor, or load in a different CSS file for editors using `CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = '/path/to/editors.css';`. Default content is probably easier to implement as part of the CMS you're using.